# Can't call gganimate function

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I installed `gganimate` packages from CRAN and run the sample codes provided:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(gapminder)

ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, colour = country)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = country_colors) +
  scale_size(range = c(2, 12)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  facet_wrap(~continent) +
  # Here comes the gganimate specific bits
  labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'GDP per capita', y = 'life expectancy') +
  transition_time(year) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

But got the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("conditionCall") :    no applicable method for
>   'conditionCall' applied to an object of class "NULL"

I've already installed magick, so could figure it our what's going on here.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the facet_wrap first. I can't test though.

Comment: Nope, still the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: This worked for me exactly as written; tested with `gganimate_0.9.9.9999` and `ggplot2_3.1.0`

Comment: Not sure why. But I've fixed it after I updated R to 3.5.2, previously it was 3.4.3.